# Fresh Install Ubuntu 22.04 - unable to see files or folders?

Tags: files, directory

Ubuntu 22.04 Crashed on me and I was unable to recover, so reinstalled (not on this device)

Now installed and I can see the drive...

But all my folders and files are missing?

on running Gdisk I get below.

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:

  MBR: not present

  BSD: not present

  APM: not present

  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.

sda                                                                                                                                         1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda1      ext4     1.0   2TB image saving 735e126b-dc1a-4add-be58-0dd9a591d8e0    1.7T     0% /mnt/735e126b-dc1a-4add-be58-0dd9a591d8e0   1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
sdb         ext4     1.0   Kingston-SSD-240 c9892f4e-2e9b-494b-9aed-56bc4d43e8b9                                                          223.6G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdc                                                                                                                                           0B root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0                                                                                                                                        1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
sr1                                                                                                                                        1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
zram0                                                                                           [SWAP]                                     15.6G root  disk  brw-rw----
nvme1n1     ext4     1.0   FireCuda 2tb     f1285141-d59b-495a-8437-5b6981c59f88    1.7T     0% /mnt/f1285141-d59b-495a-8437-5b6981c59f88   1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
nvme0n1                                                                                                                                   931.5G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     FAT32                  16FE-363F                             504.9M     1% /boot/efi                                   512M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4     1.0                    e90c5e60-288a-4182-a1f3-a78e5a189ff0  606.1G    29% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell      931G root  disk  brw-rw----
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Model: ATA KINGSTON SHFS37A (scsi)

Disk /dev/sdb: 240GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: loop

Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  240GB  240GB  ext4

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

I have obviously done something wrong, as I had removed this drive before install to make sure I installed 22.04 on the right SSD drive.

Can anyone please help me recover my files?

In basic English please, I do know my way around Ubuntu, but would say I am a beginner and easily confused

Many thanks in advance
```

Comment: The new installation is on a separate disk from the one you want to view files on? Could you post the output of `sudo lsblk -f -m | grep -v '^loop'` (remember you can format text with trippel backticks(```) above and under to create a code block)

Comment: wont allow me to post it ? says too long ???

Also do not understand last part ??


                                                                                                /

Comment: Edit your original question and add the output with a description of what the output is there. Comments are not meant or long texts :)

Comment: ok think i have done it

Comment: Are your files on the 240 GB SSD?

Comment: Yes they are :( :(

Comment: Sorry about slow response am disabled and not always well enough to sit here

Comment: Does not seem like there's a partition table on sdb drive. Could you edit question with output from: `sudo parted /dev/sdb print`

Comment: Model: ATA KINGSTON SHFS37A (scsi)

Disk /dev/sdb: 240GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: loop

Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  240GB  240GB  ext4

This drive has all my important backup files and was working before crash and had to reinstall.

Comment: By no means an expert on this, but could you try `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/mydrive` where mydrive is the name you want the mounting point to be called. Then run `sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/mydrive`. Your drive should hopefully be available at `/mnt/mydrive`. This will reset every time you restart the machine, but let me know if it succeeds and we can get on to how to permanently mount it if you're interested.

Comment: Will try when I get home at hosp at moment

Comment: managed to find mnt dir, but nothing in there.

Currently have R-Linux running have recovered about 10% of usable files so far !.
Nothing Crtitcal has been recovered so far as not complete !!

But still sorting thru, At least It is a start, while other options are being explored.

Comment: Sorry in Hospital with kidney problems, so will answer as soon as I can get back home